# USB unmounts after first access

Tags: usb, usb-power

I am currently running Raspbian Jessie on a four-node Pi cluster server.  I run an nginx load-balancer on one, and three Apache2 server clones on the others.  I recently added a new domain and virtual server to the Apache config files and everything was working peachy.

Then NewWave went down for about 15 hours, and when it came back up, suddenly my USB device wouldn't stay mounted.  It mounts upon rebooting, but it quickly unmounts after I access it once. The device is named `UUID=0C21-5650` and mounted at `/mnt/usb`.

Here is my `/etc/fstab` file for the nginx Pi:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=0C21-5650  /mnt/usb exfat  nofail,uid=<my username>,gid=nogroup   0   0
```

On the server Pi instances, I have this in the `/etc/fstab` files:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
<my ip address>:/mnt/usb /mnt/nfs nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

How do I keep the USB device from unmounting?

Edit: What I, actually, receive is a "Forbidden" error after the first access.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: I physically removed the USB, plugged it into my laptop, and used windows to run a Scan and Fix.  Problem Solved!  Seems simple for such a frustrating problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.